# How to get the controller and action names in .net core using httpcontextaccessor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Now I am working on converting .Net MVC app to .Net Core App

To Log the events we are using "HttpContext" in MVC

```
LoggerException loggerException = new LoggerException();
loggerException.ApplicationName = "Service";
loggerException.Level = logLevel;
loggerException.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
loggerException.UserController = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments[2];
loggerException.Action = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments[3];
loggerException.IpAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

in .Net Core "IHttpContextAccessor" is replacement for the "HttpContext".
I am unable to get the User controller and Action

My Current .net Core Code

```
LoggerException loggerException = new LoggerException();
loggerException.ApplicationName = appName;
loggerException.Level = logLevel;
loggerException.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
//loggerException.UserController = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null ? httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.ToString() : string.Empty;
//loggerException.Action = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null ? httpContextAccessor.HttpContext. : string.Empty;
loggerException.IpAddress = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null ? httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Comment: In this particular case you would need to use the [`ActionContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.actioncontextaccessor) which should provide you with access to the desired properies via the action context which also has access to the HttpContext

Comment: Once you've got the action context, `actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller.GetType()` gets you the controller. `actionContext.ActionDescriptor` gets you the name of the action.

Answer (score 7):

Get the [RouteData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.routedata?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for the current request in the [IActionContextAccessor.ActionContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.iactioncontextaccessor.actioncontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2) Property ,  then get the controller and action name like below.

```
var rd = actionContextAccessor.ActionContext.RouteData;
string currentController = rd.Values["controller"].ToString();
string currentAction = rd.Values["action"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Xueli Chen's answer, if you want to get the controller and action names from a BaseController, use the `filterContext` as so:

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
       string controller = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
       string action = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

       //your other code here...
       ...
       base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

This worked in MVC Core 3.1. for me.